# How to use Dispatch?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await

The compiler said,

> Cannot pass function of type '() async -> Void' to parameter expecting
> synchronous function type

[image]

This is the problem code：

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {    
    await CreateFolder()
    
    do {
        let FilePath = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        let FileName = UUID().uuidString
        try! Image.pngData()!.write(to: FilePath.appendingPathComponent("Images").appendingPathComponent("\(FileName).png"))
    } catch {
        Prompt(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you should avoid `!` and `try!`. You don’t want your app crashing if there is an issue. Also, method and variable names should always start with a lowercase letter (e.g., `createFolder`, `fileName`, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

We can tell that `CreateFolder` is not an `async` method, and as a result, you should not `await` it when calling it from within the GCD dispatch.

But the deeper problem is that you should avoid GCD queues when using async-await. You want to use the Swift concurrency cooperative thread pool. To do that, you would use `Task`.

But you do not want `Task { ... }` (or `Task.init { ... }`). If you want this behavior of running it in the background (like your global queue example), you would create a `detached` task:

```
Task.detached {
    CreateFolder() // you may now need the `await`, unless this function is marked as `nonisolated`
    
    ...
}
```

We use `Task { ... }` when we want to launch a task on the current actor, but one that honors the Swift concurrency contract to never prevent forward progress. We use `Task.detached { ... }` when the code being run is slow and synchronous and does not honor the Swift concurrency contract.

Answer (score 1):

Async methods call in a function that does not support concurrency.
You can use `Task.init`

```
Task.init {
            do {
                   _ = try await CreateFolder()
                   let FilePath = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
                           let FileName = UUID().uuidString
                           try! Image.pngData()!.write(to: FilePath.appendingPathComponent("Images").appendingPathComponent("\(FileName).png"))
               } catch {
                   Prompt(error.localizedDescription)
               }
           }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `await` from `DispatchQueue` closure.

Fixed：

```
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
   
    
    CreateFolder()
    
    do {
        let FilePath = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        let FileName = UUID().uuidString
        try! Image.pngData()!.write(to: FilePath.appendingPathComponent("Images").appendingPathComponent("\(FileName).png"))
    } catch {
        Prompt(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    }
```